# What should the custom design for this SE network be?

Tags: discussion

Can we commission someone to build it? What does SE allow? It'd be great to get a list of recent launched SE sites opinion and description of the process so we're not shooting in the dark.

Comment: Could it be changed while beta? In the Area51 QA is a note that the final design is select after the beta ends.

Comment: It's probably too early to think about this. We have to show enough traction to be a full-time site for this to even be an issue. It looks like that will be at least 3-4 months and can be a year or two to get to that point.

Comment: It's never too early to begin discussions about an issue.

Comment: +1 to just get it commissioned (subject to the rules SX applies to such things).

Comment: Actually, the design issue is quite easily a year or more into the future and is not relevant on the first day. The 7 questions blog post is [not quite accurate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201776/200868). This is a [community maintained newer resource that describes the "essential questions".](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201776/200868)

Comment: I would suggest deleting the "7 Essential Meta Questions for Every Beta" then, or updating it to reflect reality. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange states the following:

> Each community has to own the design and governance of their site.
>   They can’t always expect us to show up and say, “Hey guys, which logo
>   do you like?” Each community should work out how they’re going to come
>   up with a logo on their own. But self governance is more about
>   figuring out organically how all the tasks of defining and maintaining
>   a community are going to get accomplished.

My suggestion is we should engage the CLT on this as we are discussing and making determinations as the relate to Joomla! branding.

I'd love to see a 'Joomla! Stack Exchange Design Competition' organized by the CLT.

Taking into the ongoing discussions '[Could we update the 7 essential questions...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201776/could-we-update-the-7-essential-meta-questions-blog-post-or-not-link-it-promi)'

I think this approach would provide the 'least drama' and be the most fun.

We could even use the features of this Meta site to show designs, comment and up/down vote.

Comment: I like the idea of a design election. Would designs be allowed to re-use/modify the existing joomla logo?

Comment: I think those are decisions for the CLT/OSM - as Andrew has suggested, it's probably a good idea to form a working group and administer this - but I'd love to see different designs by folks out there!

Comment: Great idea but maybe one for the Google group...