# Is there a Joomla! CLT point-of-contact or working group for the Joomla! Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, design

In discussing the some matters as they relate to the Joomla! Stack Exchange site, in particular the '[What should the custom design for the SE network be?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-the-custom-design-for-this-se-network-be)' suggestions are to involve the Joomla! CLT.   I've also heard suggestions that the CLT should form a Joomla! Stack Exchange Working Group.

Is there currently a point-of-contact on the CLT or a CLT JSE Working Group?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any contact, and I doubt it would make sense. JSE is community supported and isn't owned by Joomla.
Even if you could take "ownership", I wouldn't be sure if it's CLT or PLT who would have to be responsible as it's for both developers and users :-)

Maybe the marketing group would make more sense anyway for design/logo questions :)

Comment: Good clarification - the link for the Marketing Working Group is at http://docs.joomla.org/Marketing_Working_Group

Team members are at http://docs.joomla.org/Marketing_Working_Group_Members

Scope includes:

"Covering how different communities utilize the Joomla! eco-system."

Comment: I'm coming around to the opinion that the CLT and PLT are great at managing Joomla property. JSE isn't Joomla property so I think it makes sense that it remain independent.

Comment: @Andrew - Despite the fact that I'm currently in disagreement with the basis of my JED question being closed, I think that so far the moderators are doing an exceptional job and that SE is in good hands 'as is.'  It's doing great and I think it's really up to us to continue that effort and encourage more involvement.